# Climate zone classification using the Holdridge method

Tags: climate

I have to classify the climate zones for [Western Ghats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Ghats) using the Holdridge method. The classifiers are temperature, rainfall, elevation. Elevation is constant. But for temperature and rainfall how many years of data should I take? Should I take mean annual temperature just for the recent year or for a certain period?